# How to update column with numbers for multiple sets of rows?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that has more than 500.000 rows. Here's what i need - For every 1000 rows i need to update a column value to a sequential numbers starting from 1. For instance the table below:

```
ID      | NAME  | EMAIL         | PHONE      | FLAG
1       | Peter | pete@mail.com | 12345678   |
.
.
.
.
500000  | Josef  | jos@mail.com | 987654321  |
```

So for first 1000 rows i need the value of column `FLAG` to be 1, next 1000 rows 2 etc and the last group of 1000 or less than 1000 rows to next sequence number

The final output what i need is as below:

```
ID      | NAME  | EMAIL         | PHONE      | FLAG
1       | Peter | pete@mail.com | 12345678   |  1
.
.
1000    | Sashi | sash@mail.com | 2353553    |  1
1001    | Veer  | veer@mail.com | 33453453   |  2 
.
.
2000    | Ash   | ash@mail.com  | 235427127  |  2
.
.
499001  | Duster| dust@mail.com | 3434343    | 500
500000  | Josef  | jos@mail.com | 987654321  | 500
.
.
```

I can write this query

```
update table
set flag = 1
where rownum <= 1000 and flag is null;
```

The above query takes lots of time manually. Is there anyway i can use some kind of for loop to do this or any better query. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update table
   set flag = trunc((id - 1) / 1000) + 1;
```